# unhashable type 'list' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using the following code to count the number of occurrences of a particular number in a numpy array, sort the dictionary in a descending order and then return it

```
km_0 = [indian,chinese,italian,mexican,indian,indian,chinese,italian] #numpy array
#The ord_dict should be like this {indian:3, chinese:2, italian:2, mexican:1} 

def labels(cluster):
    label_count ={}
    for i in cluster[0]:
        if i in label_count:
            label_count[i] += 1
        else:
            label_count[i] =1
    ord_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(label_count.items(), key=lambda kv:kv[1], reverse=True))

    return ord_dict
```

function call

```
lc = labels(km_0)
```

However, it throws up the following error

```
<ipython-input-8-72f0a128bdd4> in labels(cluster)
      9     label_count ={}
     10     for i in cluster[0]:
---> 11             if i in label_count:
     12                 label_count[i] += 1
     13             else:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Print the value of `j` it is of type `list`

Comment: First off `j` is undefined do you mean `i`, second are you trying to look if `j` is a key of the dictionary `label_count` or the `value`, I'm guessing key.

Comment: You need to tell us what `km_0` is.

Comment: Do you want `for j in cluster[0]:` instead of `i`?

Comment: It should be easy to mock up a running example of your problem. As stands, you want us to find bugs in code you haven't shown. That doesn't have a high success rate!

Comment: either j is defined somewhere else, and your code is not sufficient to reproduce the issue, or j should be i, and the question should be closed as typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of building your own counter you could employ from `collection` `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
x = "hello world"
print(OrderedDict(sorted(Counter(x).items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True))) 
#prints OrderedDict([('l', 3), ('o', 2), (' ', 1), ('e', 1), ('d', 1), ('h', 1), ('r', 1), ('w', 1)])
```

I still don't know what `j` is for yours I'm guessing it's a typo for `i`

Edited:

Above works for normal Arrays but for numpy use the follow using numpy's `unique()` function call :

```
#replace array_name with like your `i`
unique, counts = numpy.unique(array_name, return_counts=True)

#Then zip them together to make a dictionary

counted = dict(zip(unique, counts))

#then toss it into OrderedDict

print(OrderedDict(sorted(counted.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)))
```

For more information on numpy.unique [see here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

Comment: Will not work for ndarrays because they, too, are unhashable.

Comment: Oh OP updated his question, Guess I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the typo has already been addressed, I'll go another route. If you're looking specifically for `numpy.array`, then you can use MooingRawr's solution using `Counter`. However, to add a bit more performance, you can use a native Numpy counter such as `count_nonzero`.

```
import numpy as np

def cnt(arr):
    counts = {i: np.count_nonzero(arr == i) for i in range(arr.min(), arr.max() + 1)}
    return OrderedDict(sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

x = np.random.random_integers(50, size=100)
y = np.random.random_integers(50, size=(10, 10))
```